# Redirect users visiting mobile site from desktop

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile, desktop

i created 2 different website, one for mobile and one for desktop using Wordpress! I used a plugin called equivalent mobile redirect in order to redirect mobile users to the mobile site when they visit the desktop one! Now i need to do this vice versa and i cannot seem to find a efficient way! Any ideas?

Comment: Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/

Comment: This does exactly the same thing with the plugin i used! I need the same thing this but vice versa! Detect user that is from desktop and then redirect them to a different page! This detects if the user is from mobile device, not from desktop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code if you don't want to use Javascript. You can use WordPress's detect mobile function to redirect if visitor is on desktop browser.

```
if(!wp_is_mobile()){
    // If not using mobile
    wp_redirect( "https://your_desktop_site.com");
    exit;
}
```

You can add this code to your theme's functions.php file and it will work.

Comment: Yo this works like a charm! Excellent thank you! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can check with javascript:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if(isMobile.any()){
    // Mobile!
} else {
    // Desktop
}
```

Comment: I did not try this out because the bellow technique is much more easier to apply! Thank you for putting the effort though! Apreciate it1